# Hide header text and header toolbar in Outlook addin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I was searching for few days and cannot find any solution. Do you know how to hide the header text and header "toolbar" in the adjoining Outlook addin?

[image]

I dont want to have the text "My custom addin" and i dont want to have this "+" and line.

Comment: Show us some of your relevant code used to create the toolbar.

Comment: I dont understand. This is a standard toolbar created by MS. All what I want to hide/remove this.

Comment: So perhaps show the code that creates that button1 with yellow background and specify the target version of Outlook.

Comment: There are lots of outlook related SDKs for a lot of different versions and ports. Please be specific, which outlook version? Which type of plugin?

Comment: Nice reputation bounty, but still totally unclear what you are trying to do here. Did you write your own add-in which behaves like this, or did someone else install this add-in and you want to have it removed? Which Outlook version is also quite crucial, e.g. 2003 or 2013 may behave differently.

Comment: Sorry guys, i was outside the computer life.. Excel 2013, Visual Studio 2013 > Outlook 2013 AddIn (project template) and i have added one new item > Outlook Form Region > New > Adjoining > Appear everywhere > All message classes > Finish > I have changed the BackColor to yellow > and i have just add new controlL Button.

When i start my addin i can see this title and "collapse/expand buton (plus)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be happier with a "Custom Task Pane."  It still has some UI associated with it, but it's prettier.

[image]

Or, you can use a blank space (ie. " ") for the title:

[image]

To create one, create a UserControl in your project.  That's MyTaskPane below.  Then, in your ThisAddIn class, create the task pane for windows that you want it on.  The following would create the task pane on every window.

You should also remove the task panes when each window closes as described in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx).

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Inspectors _inspectors;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTaskPane pane = new MyTaskPane();
        var taskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(pane, "My Custom Task Pane");
        taskPane.Visible = true;

        _inspectors = Application.Inspectors;
        _inspectors.NewInspector += Inspectors_NewInspector;
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        MyTaskPane pane = new MyTaskPane();
        var taskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(pane, "My Custom Task Pane", Inspector);
        taskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionBottom;
        taskPane.Visible = true;
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer. You are thinking about Task Pane title, am i right? Actually i know about task panes, but this is not what i want. This is a backup soltuion, but i would like to have the standard Form Region. Any other idea? One one commercial addin propably have the posibilities to create this kind of form without this so this is propably something possible.

Comment: Don't think a standard form region will work for what you want.  Add-ins that add what look like form regions are actually using lower-level Windows API's to insert their own child window into the Outlook window and moving Outlook's child windows around to make space.  Microsoft actually has/had an article describing how to do it, but I can't find it now.  But as @m_collard's answer points out, Add-in express has that customization pre-built so you can just create them more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If its Form Region's you are looking for, have a look at [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com). They have a product called [Regions for Outlook and VSTO](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-regions/index.php).

**Key features**

Advanced Regions provide developers several unique advantages over the traditional Outlook Form Regions available in VSTO projects:

- You can add regions to practically all Outlook windows
- You can create form regions for Inspector windows and view regions for Outlook Explorer windows
- Your regions work for all versions of Outlook from 2003 to 2013
- Your regions are shared (multiple regions can share the same area with the ability to switch between them)
- Your regions can be hidden and minimized Your regions can be dragged between Outlook panes

[image: Folder view pane regions]
Folder view pane regions

[image: Reading pane regions]
Reading pane regions

[image: Task pane dock based regions]
Task pane dock based regions